# How to make a promise based HTTP post request (NodeJS) from inside an Azure function?

Tags: node.js, http-post, axios, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a scenario where an event hub is receiving data and an Azure function is triggered to fetch the data, and the Azure function should make a POST request with that fetched data as payload and get the response from server. I am using promise based npm Http module 'Axios', as the response time may vary based on the payload. (Azure functions are in NodeJS); The problem is, no Post requests are going through

Tried async - await call for Post request, still not working.

here is the code

```
module.exports = async function (context, eventHubMessages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array ${eventHubMessages}`);

    var data = {};

    eventHubMessages.forEach((message, index) => {
        context.log(`Processed message ${message}`);
        data = message;
    });

    const axios = require('axios');
    module.exports=async function(context,req){

      let response=  await axios.post('http:example.com/post',     
        { 
          data 
        } 
        )
        .then((res) => {
        context.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        context.log(res)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        context.error(error)
        })

        context.log(`Output content: ${res}`);

        }
};
```

Here is the function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "eventHubMessages",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "name-eventhub",
      "connection": "eventhub-key",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out"
    }
   ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
Processed message [object]
statusCode : 200
Output content: response // print response in here
```

Actual output:

```
Processed message [object]
```

No status code or response is being displayed in the output.

Comment: You have another problem here, you have your module.exports assigned twice. You only want to do that once. I know lambda, not azure functions, so I'm not sure how exactly the function signature, but you definitely don't want two module.exports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `await` the promise, you don't need to chain `then` and `catch`

```
const axios = require('axios');
module.exports=async function(context,req){
  try {
    const response =  await axios.post('http:example.com/post', {data})
    context.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`);
    context.log(response);
    return response; // or return a custom object using properties from response
  } catch (error) {
    // If the promise rejects, an error will be thrown and caught here
    context.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This piece of code works like charm, I am getting response back from the post request.  But I am also getting an error `[Error] Error: Choose either to return a promise or call 'done'.  Do not use both in your script.` And the function terminates itself after waiting for about 5 mins.

Comment: This error has been resolved by calling `context.done()`, before `return response;` in the try block.